# Transfer large files with rsync to USB drive

Tags: mount, rsync

I am currently trying to optimize an transfer process from an internal disk to a USB drive.
The files that I am trying to transfer are in the range of 10-30 GB.
The USB mounted disk is with a USB 3 interface and a Samsung solid state disk.
I would like to have progress of the complete transfer, so I can monitor the process.
Currently I have attempted these commands:

```
rsync -AW --info=progress2 --no-compress /home/user/rosbags/*.bag /media/upload_disk/
```

```
rsync -aWAXE --info=progress2 --no-compress /home/user/rosbags/*.bag /media/upload_disk/
```

The transfer works but the speed is rather slow after a few seconds.
It starts at 300-400MB/s and after a few seconds ends up at 30-50MB/s.
I have attempted to find a way to set blocksize for rsync, but this does to seem to work locally. What other methods could I attempt to speed up the process ?

---

To provide a bit more information.
dmesg give me:

```
[66590.546301] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[66590.701545] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0715, bcdDevice= 0.00
[66590.701550] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[66590.701553] usb 1-2: Product: VLI Product String
[66590.701555] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: VLI Manufacture String
[66590.701557] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 000000123B79
[66590.706317] scsi host4: uas
[66590.709257] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  SSD 870 QVO      SVQ0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[66590.710791] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[66590.711859] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[66590.712029] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[66590.712033] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 2f 00 00 00
[66590.712346] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[66590.712722] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[66590.778611]  sde: sde1
[66590.814915] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[66591.318592] EXT4-fs (sde1): recovery complete
[66591.324257] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

In my view the "High-speed" should mean the disk is mounted to utilize USB 3.0 speeds. But I might have overlooked something.

In /etc/fstab the disk is mounted as

```
LABEL=upload_disk /media/upload_disk/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,rw,users 0 0
```

Currently I am mounting the disk manually , when it is attached.
The sync flag is added to ensure it writes to the disk directly.
I have attempted to remove the sync flag, but the result was the same.

Comment: Very likely the high speed is your write cache memory filling up.  After that, the bottleneck is probably waiting for the USB disk to catch up on writes.  The only way to make it faster is to replace the USB drive with a faster one.

Comment: What does "Samsung solid state disk" mean? What are you using?

Comment: Then it is likely the USB-SATA controller. The disk itself is a Samsung 870 QVO 4TB, so it should not be the bottleneck.
Problem is that when I test with the internal write disk test in Ubuntu I get 400-450 Mb/s. So the solution for now is to replace the USB SATA controller an see where that takes me.

Comment: If it's running 40MB/sec or so that means it's running in USB 2 mode. You should look in the dmesg output and see which USB speed it is using (Full-speed, High-speed, etc).

Comment: Is this a one-off thing or something that needs to run at regular intervals? I'm just asking because since you asked your question, you could have transferred between 15 and 25 TB with `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the USB SATA converter I got speed of 100-200MB/s with rsync.
DD now provides speed of 450-600 MB/s for individual files.